# Javascript convert dropdown to text ONLY if text is clicked

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript to distinguish if the dropdown text is clicked or if the down arrow is clicked?

There are many answers here on how to convert a DD to a textbox, eg:
[Convert drop-down into textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9258816/convert-drop-down-into-textbox)

BUT, I would like the DD to change into a textbox ONLY if the text is clicked.

If the arrow is clicked I would like it to function as a dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no function that can allow you to click on a certain part of a default HTML element like Drop Down.

When you click on the inspect element, you'll see that the Drop down is a basic unit and can't be divided into sub-elements so that you can fetch teh exact area that is clicked for drop-down